# Write Ruby Hash with duplicate values without repeating value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in a rails controller:

```
@users = User.where(["first_name = :first_name or
                    last_name = :last_name or
                    company = :company",
                    { first_name: term, last_name: term,
                    company: term }])
```

Term is `term = params[:search]`

I don't like that I'm repeating `term`

```
{ first_name: term, last_name: term,
                        company: term }
```

is there a DRYER way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@users = User.where("first_name = :term OR
  last_name = :term OR company = :term", term: term)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hash syntax for setting the parameters

```
users = User.where('first_name = :term OR 
                    last_name = :term OR
                    company = :term', 
  term: term)
```